# New line after \subsection in amsbook

Tags: sectioning, amsbook

How can I get a new line after the subsection command in the amsbook template?

```
\subsection*{Nursery Rhyme} Mary had a little lamb
```

does not put Nursery rhyme on one line and Mary had a little lamb on the next, which is where I want it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What does this have to do with math mode?

Comment: Sorry!! my bad!

Comment: Do you want the same behavior for *all* subsections? Should *any* subsection be numbered?

Comment: no. I don't want any of the subsections to be numbered. But I don't want the text in all subsections to begin on a new line either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `amsbook` style, subsections are realized inline.

You can introduce a line break by adding `\mbox{}` (that is, an empty text) and starting a new paragraph afterwards.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} % subsections are not numbered

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{Section}

Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens

\subsection{Normal}

Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens

\subsection{With break}\mbox{}

Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens
Some text to show what happens

\end{document}
```

By setting `secnumdepth` to 1, only chapters (level 0) and sections (level 1) will be numbered.

[image]

Comment: \mbox{} is not working in my case

Comment: @lexxie Did you notice the *blank line* after `\mbox{}`?

Comment: Ah-ha! No. I didn't at first. Now I did and it works. I also found out that '\subsection{Nursery Rhymes}$ $\par' also works.

Comment: @lexxie Don't do `$ $`.